# How to load image preview after successful post (Krajee bootstrap file-input plugin)

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Krajee bootstrap file-input plugin and I want to it was displayed images after successful post. But it's not working.
This is my code:

```
var resultTaiLieu = HopKhongGiay_SapXepLichHop_Service.getAllTaiLieuCuocHopByMaCuocHop(calEvent.id);
            resultTaiLieu.then(function (p1) {
                var result_Json = JSON.parse(p1.data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result_Json));
                $("#FileUpload").fileinput({
                    initialPreview: result_Json
                });
            })
```

console.log

```
["<img src='http://localhost:51157/Documents/5f189c85-238d-4e8d-a406-3f4ee83ac965_Untitled2.png'","<img src='http://localhost:51157/Documents/53c8a2e5-d031-4617-a020-c99da79aa72a_Untitled3.png'"]
```

**Updated:**
Just add attribute "refresh" into file-input

```
$("#FileUpload").fileinput('refresh', {
                        initialPreview: result_Json
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result formatting is incorrect. The result only needs to contain the link to place saved your images, not img tag.

```
["http://localhost:51157/Documents/5f189c85-238d-4e8d-a406-3f4ee83ac965_Untitled2.png","http://localhost:51157/Documents/53c8a2e5-d031-4617-a020-c99da79aa72a_Untitled3.png"]
```